# Applescript - how to compare (in an if-clause) a bundle identifier?

Tags: if-statement, syntax, compare, applescript, comparison

Something like this script

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    set frontAppID to bundle identifier of first process whose frontmost is true
end tell
```

returns `"com.apple.Safari"`

However, if I try something like

```
if frontAppID of bundle identifier of first process whose frontmost is "com.apple.safari" then
```

then it doesn't work. Obviously a bundle identifier cannot be compared with a string. How do I create a bundle identfier object I can use in my comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bundle identifier` is a string, so a string-to-string comparison is fine. The problems with your statement are: `frontAppID of bundle identifier`, which isn't valid because `frontAppID` isn't a property of `bundle identifier`; and `frontmost is` should be followed by a boolean, not a string.

Fixing these issues (and assuming you'll enclose this within the appropriate *System Events* command block):

```
    if the bundle identifier ¬
        of (the first process ¬
        whose frontmost is true) ¬
        is "com.apple.safari" then ¬
        return true
```

**P.S.** Are you aware you can also do this (without needing to call *System Events*):

```
    if application "Safari" is frontmost then return true
```

or, using the bundle identifier:

```
    if application id "com.apple.safari" is frontmost then return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntaxe is not correct. correct should be:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if (bundle identifier of first process whose frontmost is true) is "com.apple.Safari" then
        display dialog "Safari front most !"
    end if
end tell
```